# Probability of objects being grouped together in a set of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have a collection of $b$ distinct, uncoloured balls distributed among $s$ nonempty sets of known sizes.  We randomly select one ball and paint it black, and another $r$ balls and paint them red.  What's the probability that the black ball is in the same set as a red ball?

I found a formula which works for the case where $r = 1$.  Let $C$ be the set of ball sets, so $\left|C\right| = s$.  Then the probability that the black ball is in the same set as the red ball is $$\frac{\sum_{c \in C} \left|c\right| \left(\left|c\right| - 1\right)}{b \left(b-1\right)}.$$

However, I don't see how to generalize this formula to arbitrary values of $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of ways to color one ball black and $r$ balls red is
$$
b\cdot{{b-1}\choose{r}}=\frac{b!}{r!(b-r-1)!}.
$$
Of these, the number that place the black ball in a set with no red balls is
$$
\sum_{c\in C}\left|c\right|{{b - \left|c\right|}\choose{r}}=\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)!}{r!(b-\left|c\right|-r)!},
$$
where the sum is over sets such that $b-\left|c\right|\ge r.$
The probability that the black ball is in a set with at least one red ball is therefore
$$
1-\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)!(b-r-1)!}{b!(b-\left|c\right|-r)!}.
$$
In the $r=1$ case, this becomes
$$
1-\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)}{b(b-1)}=\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|}{b}-\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)}{b(b-1)}=\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(\left|c\right|-1)}{b(b-1)},
$$
agreeing with your answer.  For $r=2$, the result is
$$
1-\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)(b-\left|c\right|-1)}{b(b-1)(b-2)},
$$
and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  How can $$
1-\sum_{c\in C}\frac{\left|c\right|(b-\left|c\right|)!(b-r-1)!}{b!(b-\left|c\right|-r)!}
$$ give a correct answer for the case that there is only one set of balls (i.e., $s = 1$)?  In this case $b = \left|c\right|$, so $b - \left|c\right| - r$ must be negative, and you can't compute the factorial of a negative number.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see now that this sum, like the previous one you wrote, is meant to apply only to those sets where $b - \left|c\right| \geq r$.